# Colour profile not set when switching monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, color

I'm running OS X 10.8.5 on a mid 2011 MacBook Air. Lately I've noticed that when I attach or detach an external monitor, the relevant monitor colour profile is not actually used.

When I look in the preferences, the correct profile is always set, be it for the external monitor or for the build in screen.

The actual displayed colours however are of, which can be fixed by selecting a random other screen profile and then clicking back on the original and correct selected one. This obviously is a minor annoyance. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The color profiles (drivers) are managed by the ColorSync Utility located in your utility folder.

Open it and look what profile is been used for your monitor, then select optional one to see the changes.

There should be the factory settings and currently used profiles.

Comment: They are set correct in the ColorSync Utility, but I guess not actually used because the colours are still off. And reselecting them via the prefs fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using standard profiles or are you using a profile from a hardware calibration tool? I use a Spyder4 and there the software will always assure in the background that the right profile is activated...

Comment: I am using standard apple profiles.

Comment: Well colours will always be "off" using standard profiles. If you want reliable colors you need to calibrate with a hardware sensor... there are too much factors playing into colors of a display. It's difficult to achieve correct colors with standard profiles.